# GKE Autopilot: How to add/manage SSL Certificate to GKE autopilot

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I recently set up a GKE autopilot but realized it doesn't support webhooks which cert-manager is dependent on. What are the other options we have to add/manage SSL certificates to a GKE auto-pilot cluster?

Comment: Where/how do you intend to use the SSL certs?

Comment: And do you need wildcard certificates?

Comment: I do not need wildcards. I want to be able to use `cert-manager` to manage my SSL in a google autopilot cluster.

Comment: Sure - but are you looking tto manage SSL certs for Ingress or for other objects as well?

Comment: Probably just for the ingress

Comment: You're right, @GariSingh. It's just for ingress.

Comment: I have never tired this on an Autopilot cluster, but this might work:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#creating_an_ingress_with_a_google-managed_certificate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of May 2021, GKE Autopilot has no support for 3rd party webhooks. Without webhooks, many Kubernetes plugins such as cert-manager cannot operate correctly. Cert-manager uses a custom mutating admission webhook to manage certificates, which is immutable on GKE Autopilot.

To add/manage SSL certificates for Autopilot clusters, you should first start with this official GCP doc  [Google-managed SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs).

You can configure Google-managed SSL certificates using a ManagedCertificate custom resource, which is available in different API versions, depending on your GKE cluster version.  It's recommended that you use a newer API version.

- ManagedCertificate v1beta2 API is available in GKE cluster versions
  1.15 and later.
- ManagedCertificate v1 API is available in GKE cluster versions
  1.17.9-gke.6300 and later.

> **Note**: Google-managed SSL certificates aren't currently supported for internal HTTPS load balancers. For internal HTTPS load balancers, use self-managed SSL certificates instead. This feature is only available for Ingress for External HTTP(S) Load Balancing, can read more [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress).

To configure a Google-managed SSL certificate and associate it with an Ingress, follow the two basic steps first:

- Create a ManagedCertificate object in the same namespace as the
  Ingress.
- Associate the ManagedCertificate object to an Ingress by adding an
  annotation networking.gke.io/managed-certificates to the Ingress.
  This annotation is a comma-separated list of ManagedCertificate
  resources, cert1,cert2,cert3 for example.
  Which is mentioned in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#creating_an_ingress_with_a_google-managed_certificate).

You have to follow some [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#prerequisites):

- You must own the domain name (Google Domains or another registrar).
- Your "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" must be "gce".
- Create a reserved (static) external IP address. If you do not reserve
  an address, it may change, requiring you to reconfigure your domain's
  DNS records.

For setting up a Google-managed certificate, go through the [sample ManagedCertificate manifest](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs#setting_up_a_google-managed_certificate).

Comment: This answer is now outdated; see my alternative answer regarding cert-manager compatibility.

Comment: Some of it is outdated, but the link: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs is still very valid and in my opinion contains the best/easiest option

Answer (score 4):

cert-manager [is now compatible](https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3717#issuecomment-919299192) with GKE Autopilot.

Comment: it's still not working through kubectll apply